# .htaccess - ADD www. & REMOVE .html

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

*Hi! My english is not very good, sorry for any spelling mistakes.*

Using .htaccess I want to **add** `www.` and **remove/hide** the `.html`.

It should look something like this:

> **BEFORE --** `http://example.com/whatever.html`

> **AFTER -----** `http://www.example.com/whatever`

I have `.www` adder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

And `.html` remover

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [N]
```

How to connect them?

**NOTE:** It want remove/hide `.html` from each `.html` file on my page.

*I use this tool to test my .htaccess file: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be*

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "...and replace `https://` to `http://`" - why? You really shouldn't be redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP (that's _backwards_). In order to redirect _from_ HTTPS, you need to have already connected successfully over HTTPS anyway, so it makes the process rather pointless to begin with.

Comment: "I don't wanna change `/whatever.html` to `/whatever/`" - but that is exactly what you are doing in your example? You state that you want to remove `.html`, but in your example you are also appending a trailing slash which you don't actually mention in your requirements? "It want remove .html from each .html file on my page." - Although this isn't something you should be doing in `.htaccess`. You need to first remove the `.html` in the actual link on your page. You then use `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the URL back again.

Comment: "I use this tool to test my .htaccess file" - You need to test your rules on a real server. Unfortunately _that_ tool has got this quite wrong. It is not handling the "chained" rules correctly and it's not alerting you to the redirect-loop. The rules you posted would result in a infinite redirect-loop to `http://www.example.com/whatever//`.

Comment: You're right, I am not an `.htaccess` specialist. That's why I needed help. I had some problems with `https`, so I wanted to redirect to `http`. But when I think about it, it makes no sense. Anyway, I still have a problem with adding `www.` and removing `.html` Because when you add `www.` like this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$`
 `RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/$1`
it works like a redirect and I'm not able to remove `.html`

Comment: So, basically, you want "extensionless" URLs? However, please confirm... is the desired URL `/whatever/` (with a slash suffix), or without: `/whatever`?

Comment: Yes, I want to add `www.` and remove extension. I have this `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/`. I added this slash at the end as a visual addition only. I just like the slash at the end.

Comment: Ok, but as I mentioned above, that is not something you do in `.htaccess` (except to help with SEO later, if you are changing an existing URL). You need to actually remove the `.html` extension (and append the slash) in your HTML source. ie. `href="/whatever/"`. It doesn't sound as if you have done that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused now. Now I really don't know how to do it. I want to add `www.` and remove/hide/replace with / `.html`. I'm not talking about removing `html` when the user is on the site using javascript or something. Only about the possibility of entering to the browser eg."example.com/about", not "www.example.com/about.html"...

Comment: Now, when i write "www.mydomain.com/about" i get 404 error. Because "mydomain.com/about" does not exist. But "mydomain.com/about.html" exist and working well. In addition, I always want to redirect to `www.` because at the moment I have both `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`

Comment: Ah, in that case you don't want to remove the `.html` extension at all! In fact, you want to do the complete opposite... accept requests without an extension and redirect the request to the canonical URL (_with_ an extension). The way you described your problem initially, together with the example code, it looked like you wanted to remove the `.html` extension from your URLs, to make them look "pretty".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. As per Mr.White's nice suggestion added condition in RewriteRule part to avoid passing css or js files to rule.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: FINALLY! The whole problem was that I tried to remove the html from the link. In fact, it had to be done exactly the opposite. Sorry for my incorrect reasoning. I learned the basics of the `.htaccess` a week ago because I need this only to a few things on my website. Thank you.

Comment: @KondRoll, Your welcome, not an issue we all learn. cheers and happy learning, keep posting good questions, answers on this great site.

Comment: Instead of examining _every_ request, it would be much more efficient to exclude requests that don't already have a `.html` extension, or don't have any file extension at all. eg. `!\.\w{2,4}$`.

Comment: @MrWhite, sure, but then it wouldn't check if file is physically present or not? May be like this you mean `RewriteRule (.*)\.(?!=[\w]-{2,4})$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]` here(not tested it yet).

Comment: I'm not saying remove the filesystem check. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ would be just as I posted above. There's no need for a _capturing_ subgroup since this is not being used in the substitution string. (_Aside:_ To clarify, this directive will need to go _before_ the non-www to www redirect.)

Comment: @MrWhite, oh ok, you mean I could simply use `^` in place of `^(.*)$` if I got it correctly.

Comment: No, `!\.\w{2,4}$` in place of `^(.*)`. The regex `^(.*)` naturally matches _everything_, including requests for all static resources eg. `styles.css`. There is no point doing a filesystem check (which is relatively _expensive_) for `styles.css.html`, so by using a regex like `!\.\w{2,4}$` we avoid matching any URLs that "look like" they already map to files. Only if we request `styles` (no extension) will it then test for `styles.html`.

Comment: @MrWhite, oh ok I think got it, `RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]` is this look good to you, could you please do let me know if this looks Good before I post it to answer :) cheers.